# Dimensions of locally connected layers in Keras

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I'm attempting to build an autoencoder using `LocallyConnected1D` layers (instead of `Dense`) but am having a lot of trouble understanding how the two layer types differ—especially when it comes to output dimensionality.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape(input_shape=(input_size,), target_shape=(input_size,1))
model.add(LocallyConnected1D(encoded_size, kernel_size)
model.add(LocallyConnected1D(input_size, kernal_size_2, name="decoded_layer"))
```

This model will compile just fine, but when I go to train it...

```
model.fit(x_train, x_train,
         epochs=epochs,
         batch_size=batch_size,
         shuffle=True,
         validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

Where `x_train` and `x_test` are numpy arrays of shape (60000, 784) and (10000, 784), respectively. I get the following error on this line:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected decoded_layer to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 784)
```

Shouldn't the shape of the tensor going into `decoded_layer` be (60000, `encoded_size`, 1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you do not have to put `None` as the first dimension in your input_shape. Keras automatically assumes that there is another input dimension that is the number of samples.

Second, `LocallyConnected1D` requires a 3D input. This means that your input_shape should be in the form of (int, int), with keras inferring a shape of (None, int, int)

An example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LocallyConnected1D(64, 3, input_shape=(10,10))) #takes a 10 by 10 array for each sample
model.add(LocallyConnected1D(32, 3))
```

If you data isn't in the right shape you can always use a `Reshape()` layer. Lets say your input is in the shape of (batch_size, 50), so each sample is a 1D vector of 50 elements:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape(input_shape=(50,), target_shape=(50,1)) #makes array 3D
model.add(LocallyConnected1D(64, 3))
model.add(LocallyConnected1D(32, 3))
```

Comment: But what if I have just a 1D array that I want to encode? For example, if I have a 1D array of `n` length: [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, ...], would I put `LocallyConnected1D(64, 3, input_shape=(1, n))`?

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks again Primusa!

Comment: I'm happy to help :)

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the input into the last layer. The model will compile, but when I try to fit data to it, it gives me the following error: `Error when checking target: expected decoded_layer to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 784)` (decoded_layer is the last layer). I am passing into the `.fit` function a numpy array of size (60000, 784)--the MNIST dataset.

Comment: I'll go on a limb here and say add a reshape layer as the first layer in your model:

`model.add(Reshape(input_shape=(784,), target_shape=(784,1))`

Comment: Added source to problem description. I have a reshape layer as you suggest.

Comment: Add another reshape between your two locally connected layers.

Comment: Your first locallyconnected1D outputs a 2D vector so reshape its output into 3D then feed it into the next

Comment: Shouldn't that already happen via the `Sequential` class? I've added an intermediate `Reshape` layer, however, I'm not sure what the `target_shape` should be. Intuition tells me it should be (batch_size, encoded_size, 1), but if I make `target_shape=(encoded_size,1)` I get this error: `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Comment: you can check all the output shapes of each layer by doing `model.summary()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169008/discussion-between-primusa-and-user9509404).